# What is the purpose of Default Ignorable Code Points in font rendering?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, codepoint, pangocairo

According to [this link](http://www.unicode.org/review/pr-5.html), U+00AD is a default ignorable code point.

What exactly is the purpose of these default ignorable code points?
What is the harm if I want to render U+00AD ?

The link provides some information, but I am not really clear.

*"U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN has a null default appearance: the appearance of ther-apist is simply "therapist"; no visible glyph. In linebreak processing, it indicates a possible intra-word break. At any intra-word break that is used for a line break — whether resulting from this character or by automatic process — a hyphen glyph (perhaps with spelling changes) or some other indication can be shown, depending on language and context."*

Please clarify.

Comment: That's a pretty good description you have linked. Which part of it is not clear?

Comment: @KerrekSB:
Maybe I did not ask my question clearly.
The short version of the question is: 
What is wrong if I want to render U+00AD ?

Comment: That question makes no sense. U+AD does not have a visual representation. How do you want to render it? And *why*?